# Variable array/object in one file changes when you change it in a callback in another file

Tags: arrays, node.js, variables, object, scope

I have two files in `Node.js` where one requires the other one.

variable_test.js:

```
TEST        = require('./variable_test_external.js');

TEST.get(function(myVariable) {
    var changeMeVariable;
    console.log(myVariable);
    changeMeVariable = myVariable.epicVariable;
    changeMeVariable.evenEpicerVariable = "test3";
    TEST.get(function(myVariable2) {
        console.log(myVariable2);
    });
});
```

variable_test_external.js:

```
var testVariable = new Array({epicVariable: {evenEpicerVariable: "test1"}}, {epicVariable: {evenEpicerVariable: "test2"}});

exports.get = function(callback) {
    callback(testVariable[1]); // I know that the return is unnecessary in this example but in my real application I have return there for compactness.
}
```

This is the output when run in `Node.js` with `node variable_test.js`:

```
{ epicVariable: { evenEpicerVariable: 'test2' } }
{ epicVariable: { evenEpicerVariable: 'test3' } }
```

The `console.log(myVariable)` changes in the two `TEST.get`'s. Why does this happen?

Comment: You're changing the property value with `changeMeVariable.evenEpicerVariable = "test3";`. Why do you expect it *not* to change? You never make a copy of any of the objects, so they are still all the same objects.

Comment: See also [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/710446)

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the info! Is there an easy way of copying the object so that I don't change the original when I edit the copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in my case is the following based on the links at the bottom:

```
changeMeVariable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myVariable.epicVariable));
```

**But**, it's **much** better to manually copy it like the bottom most link like this:

```
changeMeVariable = {
    evenEpicerVariable: myVariable.epicVariable.evenEpicerVariable
}
```

n0m's answer is similar but if the `epicVariable.evenEpicerVariable` contained an object that object's reference would still be linked! (I tested it)

References:

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

http://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object/3

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference copy, not a value copy. You got the object from the array, NOT a copy of them.

```
changeMeVariable = myVariable.epicVariable;
```

This would have to fix yout problem

```
// PSEUDO CODE, i don't know the correct syntax 
changeMeVariable = {
    epicVariable = myVariable.epicVariable
};
```

Comment: Doesn't this just become an object copy in a new object?